# Usercontrol is not get the ResourceDictionary in Universal Windows Phone

Tags: uwp

I have a resource dictionary, and i refer this in App.xaml as per the below code its works fine, but the same code i gave in UserControl.xaml its not works,

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Tutorials/Controls/CustomColumnChooserTheme.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Could you suggest on this?

Comment: Maybe the path is wrong? Shouldn't it be relative?  Source is an Uri - try to add `../your relative path` - or maybe use `ms-appx:///...` schema.

Comment: Path is correct, i tried ms-appx:///Tutorials/Controls/CustomColumnChooserTheme.xaml and ../../Tutorials/Controls/CustomColumnChooserTheme.xaml but not works

Answer (score 1):

Everything should work fine, I have checked.

If your UserControl is placed inside the main project folder, just add this XAML code to your UserControl:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
     <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Tutorials/Controls/CustomColumnChooserTheme.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```